# Change the color of the icon vs make icons in many color

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I am confused between changing the color of the icon at run time using:

```
Drawable x = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_xx);
x.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#000000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

or creating many icons files in each color that I need ! 
Any help ! THANK YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on an amount of pictures. I would create images for each if there are only a few colors (White and Black for example). But for hundreds of colors, I think it's better to use a filter.

Actually, if you app support only SDK version > lollipop
you can you use tint parameter in xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
    android:tint="@color/red_tint"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install  MaterialDesignIconGeneratorPlugin following this link
https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question!